# How to populate a form field via javascript with an SQL query of WordPress table

Tags: javascript, sql, wordpress, contact-form-7

I have a Contact 7 form with a hidden field labeled confirmation_number. I need to populate that field with an SQL query.

This is my SQL query

```
select count(*)
from wp_postmeta
where meta_value = "used"
```

This is the code I put in my functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'add_confirmation_number' );
function add_confirmation_number() {
  $page_id = get_the_ID();
  if($page_id===11699 || $page_id===11709 || $page_id===11710 ||$page_id===11729 ){
        $wpcf7 = WPCF7_ContactForm::get_current();
        global $wpdb;
        $confirmation_number = $wpdb->get_var(("SELECT count(*) FROM $wpdb->wp_postmeta  WHERE meta_value = 'used' "));
        return $confirmation_number;
    ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
            document.getElementById('confirmation-number').value = <?php echo $confirmation_number ?>;
    </script>

    <?php
  }
}
```

I am getting an error `Undefined property: wpdb::`

But I have tried everything to fix this syntax and nothing works. I'm also not sure if I'm using
`$wpdb` correctly. I'm a budding Wordpress dev, so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a few things. One, is that your script is probably never loading because you have as `return $confirmation_number` which would stop propagation of the function. The second is that `$wpdb->table_name` properties don't include the prefix. The `postmeta` table `$wpdb->postmeta`. You can also use `$wpdb->prefix` to add the prefix to tables that haven't been added to the global `$wpdb` object  if you need to access those.

I've cleaned up a few things as well, but removing the `return` statement, and changing `$wpdb->wp_postmeta` to `$wpdb->postmeta` should suffice.

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'add_confirmation_number' );
function add_confirmation_number() {
    $confirmation_page_ids = array( 11699, 11709, 11710, 11729 );

    if( in_array(get_the_ID(), $confirmation_page_ids) ){
        global $wpdb;
        $wpcf7 = WPCF7_ContactForm::get_current(); // Is this necessary? No other calls to $wpcf7 below

        $sql = "
            SELECT count(*)
            FROM   $wpdb->postmeta
            WHERE  meta_value = 'used'
        ";

        $confirmation_number = $wpdb->get_var( $sql );

        if( $confirmation_number !== null ){
            printf( '<script type="text/javascript">
                document.getElementById("confirmation-number").value = %d;
            </script>', absint($confirmation_number) );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OMG - your whole answer is much more readable. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

Change this line of code:

```
$confirmation_number = $wpdb->get_var(("SELECT count(*) FROM $wpdb->wp_postmeta  WHERE meta_value = 'used' "));
```

To:

```
$confirmation_number = $wpdb->get_var(("SELECT count(*) FROM $wpdb->postmeta  WHERE meta_value = 'used' "));
```

Aslo `return $confirmation_number;` shouldn't be there.

Comment: Hey @Zed! Your answer does work, and would be perfectly acceptable - but generally people asking questions like this benefit from a quick explanation as well. Instead of "change X to Y", you should explain _why_ changing X to Y actually works, even in just a sentence or two. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for advice. I'll definitely consider it. 